# Does the Bootstrap 3 Date/Time Picker have a bug with months view?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I've been using the [eonasdan](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) for a few months, and just implemented a month picker, but noticed in the console view for Chrome the following every time I choose a month [(this also occurs on the read the docs sample)](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#view-mode):

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:508
fillDate                                         bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:508
actions.selectMonth                              bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:754
doAction                                         bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:898
jQuery.event.dispatch                            jquery-1.11.1.js:4641
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle                 jquery-1.11.1.js:4309
```

It appears to be caused by this:

```
// widget is false after the picker is collapsed
// I've added if(!widget) return;
var daysView = widget.find('.datepicker-days'),
                    daysViewHeader = daysView.find('th'),
                    currentDate,
                    html = [],
                    row,
                    clsName;
```

For now I've added a condition that checks for the widget before calling find on it, but as it's a nuget package, I expect the next update will wipe out my change, and I don't know what implications this change would have on other uses.

Is this a known issue? Is there a work around? How do I submit this to the developer?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see this issue on the doc site. Please test and/or fork [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eonasdan/0Ltv25o8/) with an example of your issue

Comment: It was, but according to this, it has been fixed in an upcoming release https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/827